# How to up-cast to a generic object?

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I have an array of Castle windsor registration components of type IRegistration[]

In this case `ComponentRegistration<T> : IRegistration`

For each element in my array, 
if it can be upcast to ComponentRegistration<> I would like to upcast it back to `ComponentRegistration<T>` and process it.  How exactly would I do this?

I got as far as

```
foreach (var r in registrations) {
  if(typeof(ComponentRegistration<>).IsAssignableFrom(r.GetType())) {
    var cr = CAST r SOMEHOW
    DoStuff(cr);
  }
```

Comment: What is the signature of DoStuff?

Comment: Ah, Eric's here. I don't need to return to this question - it's guaranteed to get an excellent answer :)

Comment: DoStuff attaches a castle interceptor.  Unfortunately I only know how to do this in their fluent interface with the ComponentRegistration<T> or BasedOnDescriptor implementations of IRegistration.  However, I do know that all the elements of registrations are one of these two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surely if you've got an `IRegistration[]` then you're *downcasting* rather than upcasting.

However, to get to your problem, what does `DoStuff()` look like? Does it need to know the type argument for `ComponentRegistration<T>`? If not, you might be best creating a non-generic base class:

```
public abstract class ComponentRegistration : IRegistration
{
    // Anything in the original API which didn't use T
}

public class ComponentRegistration<T> : ComponentRegistration
{
    // The bits which need T
}
```

Then you could write:

```
foreach (var r in registrations)
{
    ComponentRegistration cr = r as ComponentRegistration;
    if (cr != null)
    {
        DoStuff(cr);
    }
}
```

If you really need `DoStuff` to use the generic information, you'll have to use reflection to get the appropriate type and invoke it. Avoid if possible :)

EDIT: Okay, here's an example of the reflection nastiness. It doesn't try to account for generic interfaces, as that gets even hairier.

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

class Test
{   
    static void Main()
    {
        Delegate[] delegates = new Delegate[]
        {
            (Action<int>) (x => Console.WriteLine("int={0}", x)),
            (Action<string>) (x => Console.WriteLine("string={0}", x)),
            (Func<int, int>) (x => x + 1)
        };

        MethodInfo genericPerformAction = typeof(Test).GetMethod
                                                       ("PerformAction");

        foreach (Delegate del in delegates)
        {
            Type t = DiscoverTypeArgument(del, typeof(Action<>));
            if (t == null)
            {
                // Wrong type (e.g. the Func in the array)
                continue;
            }
            MethodInfo concreteMethod = genericPerformAction.MakeGenericMethod
                (new[] { t } );
            concreteMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { del });
        }
    }

    public static void PerformAction<T>(Action<T> action)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Performing action with type {0}", typeof(T).Name);
        action(default(T));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Discovers the type argument for an object based on a generic
    /// class which may be somewhere in its class hierarchy. The generic
    /// type must have exactly one type parameter.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// The type argument, or null if the object wasn't in
    /// the right hierarchy.
    /// </returns>
    static Type DiscoverTypeArgument(object o, Type genericType)
    {
        if (o == null || genericType == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }
        if (genericType.IsInterface ||
            !genericType.IsGenericTypeDefinition || 
            genericType.GetGenericArguments().Length != 1)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Bad type");
        }

        Type objectType = o.GetType();
        while (objectType != null)
        {
            if (objectType.IsGenericType &&
                objectType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == genericType)
            {
                return objectType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
            }
            objectType = objectType.BaseType;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

EDIT: Note that *if* you're in a situation where *all* the members are derived from the relevant class, and *if* you're using C# 4, you can use dynamic binding:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

class Test
{   
    static void Main()
    {
        Delegate[] delegates = new Delegate[]
        {
            (Action<int>) (x => Console.WriteLine("int={0}", x)),
            (Action<string>) (x => Console.WriteLine("string={0}", x)),
            (Action<long>) (x => Console.WriteLine("long={0}", x)),
        };

        foreach (dynamic del in delegates)
        {
            // Yay for dynamic binding
            PerformAction(del);
        }
    }

    public static void PerformAction<T>(Action<T> action)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Performing action with type {0}", typeof(T).Name);
        action(default(T));
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I don't know of any way of testing whether it's going to manage to bind to the method successfully without just trying it and catching the relevant exception (which would be grim). Maybe Eric will be able to tell us :)

Comment: I really feel like it does not need to know the generic information, DoStuff() would attach an interceptor to be used for logging debug info. Unfortunately the Castle Windsor interface only exposes the appropriate methods to do this on the generic class.  Can you point me in the direction of the generic hack?  I'm running low on time and don't want to go down the wrong path.

Comment: Okay - will come up with equivalent using Delegate and Action<T> as the types involved.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cannot do this without either

1. Having a non-generic form of ComponentRegistration
2. Knowing T
3. Using a reflection hack

**EDIT** the reflection hack

Essentially you'll need to use reflection to grab the runtime type.  Inspect the type to grab the generic T in ComponentRegistration.  Then use that T to instantiate an instance of method DoStuff and pass in the object as a parameter.

Comment: what kind of reflection hack?  This is for a module to be run to assist with debugging so I have no problem with hacking it.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm surprised that there isn't a set of OS libraries to do this sort of thing already.

Answer (score 0):

If the class you're trying to upcast to is a non-generic derived from the generic, you can get around this problem by casting through **Object**:

```
abstract class A<T> where T : A<T>
{
    T derived;
    void foo()
    {
        B b1 = (B)derived;      // Error CS0030: 'Cannot convert type 'T' to 'B'
        B b2 = (B)(Object)derived;  // Ok
    }
};

class B : A<B> { };
```