# Why does casting give CS0030, while "as" works?

Tags: c#, generics, c#-4.0, casting

Suppose I have a generic method:

```
T Foo(T x) {
    return x;
}
```

So far so good. But I want to do something special if it's a Hashtable.  (I know this is a completely contrived example.  `Foo()` isn't a very exciting method, either.  Play along.)

```
if (typeof(T) == typeof(Hashtable)) {
    var h = ((Hashtable)x);  // CS0030: Cannot convert type 'T' to 'System.Collections.Hashtable'
}
```

Darn. To be fair, though, I can't actually tell if this should be legal C# or not. Well, what if I try doing it a different way?

```
if (typeof(T) == typeof(Hashtable)) {
    var h = x as Hashtable;  // works (and no, h isn't null)
}
```

That's a little weird. According to MSDN, `expression as Type` is (except for evaluating expression twice) the same as `expression is type ? (type)expression : (type)null`.

What happens if I try to use the equivalent expression from the docs?

```
if (typeof(T) == typeof(Hashtable)) {
    var h = (x is Hashtable ? (Hashtable)x : (Hashtable)null);  // CS0030: Cannot convert type 'T' to 'System.Collections.Hashtable'
}
```

The only documented difference between casting and `as` that I see is "the `as` operator only performs reference conversions and boxing conversions".  Maybe I need to tell it I'm using a reference type?

```
T Foo(T x) where T : class {
    var h = ((Hashtable)x);  // CS0030: Cannot convert type 'T' to 'System.Collections.Hashtable'
    return x;
}
```

What's going on?  Why does `as` work fine, while casting won't even compile?  Should the cast work, or should the `as` not work, or is there some other language difference between casting and `as` that isn't in these MSDN docs I found?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that sentence you're quoting from MSDN existed before generics did.

Comment: Still though, if that's all there is... Interesting question for sure!

Comment: Is this a dupe, or just closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/884315/how-to-up-cast-to-a-generic-object ?

Comment: I would say it's related -- I'm coming at it from the other direction.  And this wouldn't be the first time I tried to follow out-of-date MSDN docs, if that's the case!

Comment: @Ken: I think the title on the other question is backwards, it looks to me like it's actually the same case.

Answer (score 20):

Ben's answer basically hits the nail on the head, but to expand on that a bit:

The problem here is that people have a natural expectation that a generic method will do the same thing that the equivalent non-generic method would do if given the types at compile time. In your particular case, people would expect that if T is short, then `(int)t` should do the right thing -- turn the short into an int. And `(double)t` should turn the short into a double. And if T is byte, then `(int)t` should turn the byte into an int, and `(double)t` should turn the byte into a double... and now perhaps you begin to see the problem.  The generic code we'd have to generate would basically have to *start the compiler again at runtime and do a full type analysis, and then dynamically generate the code to do the conversion as expected*.

That is potentially expensive; we added that feature in C# 4 and if that's what you really want, you can mark the objects as being of type "dynamic" and a little stripped-down version of the compiler will start up again at runtime and do the conversion logic for you.

But that expensive thing is typically not what people want.

The "as" logic is *far* less complicated than the cast logic because it does not have to deal with any conversions other than boxing, unboxing and reference conversions. It does not have to deal with user-defined conversions, it does not have to deal with fancy representation-changing conversions like "byte to double" that turn one-byte data structures into eight-byte data structures, and so on.

That's why "as" is allowed in generic code but casts are not.

All that said: you are almost certainly doing it wrong. If you have to do a type test in generic code *your code is not generic*.  This is a really bad code smell.

Comment: To add one example where it may not be a code smell, the `Enumerable.Count<TSource>` Method is generic, yet checks if TSource is an ICollection to get a huge, huge performance benefit by calling .Count instead of iterating. Yes, an edge case and I agree that it's not a code smell, but there can be good reasons for it.

Comment: @MichaelStum: I take your point. However, it is still a pretty "generic" thing to do to ask *an object* "do you support this interface?" Non-generic code does that sort of thing as well. But when you say "if T happened to be exactly the type HashTable then..." then T is not at all being used in a generic manner.

Comment: Ah, I think I see. Philosophically, you say that "I care that this implements a method Count with the behavior I expect as defined by ICollection (aka. it shouldn't do funky stuff that I wouldn't expect like Counting from 1 to X through the loudspeakers)"? (Just trying to understand the design philosophy behind this other than "It speeds up things a lot")

Comment: I agree that it's a definite code smell; that being said I think that one of the places where it would be of great use is in situations where you would use partial specialization in C++. Maybe partial specialization is a code smell too, but it's a feature I miss between templates and generics...

Answer (score 9):

The cast operator in C# can:

- box/unbox
- upcast/downcast
- call a user-defined conversion operator

`as Hashtable` always means the second.

By eliminating value types with the constraint, you've knocked out option 1, but it's still ambiguous.

---

Here are the two "best" approaches that both work:

```
Hashtable h = x as Hashtable;
if (h != null) {
    ...
}
```

or

```
if (x is Hashtable) {
    Hashtable h = (Hashtable)(object)x;
    ...
}
```

The first needs only one type test, so it's very efficient.  And the JIT optimizer recognizes the second one, and treats it like the first (at least when dealing with non-generic types, I'm not sure about this particular case.)

Comment: So you're saying casting fails because there might be conversion operators in the type? Not saying you're wrong but.. the compiler already knows the generic type is at least an `object` (the `T : class` part in the OP), so if you can cast `object`s blind, shouldn't you also be able to do it for generic types?

Comment: This explanation makes sense to me.  It also means the MSDN docs weren't wrong, but just confusingly written: "A is the same as B, except for case C.  Note that it's also different in way D."

Comment: @Blindy: Downcast takes precedence over user-defined conversion, when both match.  And since every object derives from `object`, a cast from `object` always matches downcast.  For example, if this code were written as `(Hashtable)(object)x;`, it would work.

Comment: "as" can also box/unbox. "someInt as object" will box, and "someObject as int?" will unbox if it is a boxed int, or give a null nullable int if it is not.

Comment: @EricLippert: Was just editing to deal with that.  But it doesn't introduce ambiguity, since `is` and `as` aren't dynamic, the compiler knows whether the target type is a reference or value type.  (Obviously you already knew that)

Answer (score 4):

"The C# compiler only lets you implicitly cast generic type parameters to Object, or to constraint-specified types, as shown in Code block 5. Such implicit casting is type safe because any incompatibility is discovered at compile-time."

See the section on Generics and Casting:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(v=vs.80).aspx#csharp_generics_topic5