# Why does as instead of a cast work?

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I have two classes, where the first class references the second class. My question is, why in the second class, the line `cl.container = this as ClassContainer<MyClass>;` does work and the explicit cast `cl.container = (ClassContainer<MyClass>)this;` does not.

```
class MyClass
{
    public ClassContainer<MyClass> container { get; set; }
}
```

second class:

```
class ClassContainer<T> where T : MyClass
{
    public ClassContainer()
    {
        MyClass cl = new MyClass();
        cl.container = this as ClassContainer<MyClass>; // works
        cl.container = (ClassContainer<MyClass>)this;   // does not work
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say 'does not work' does it throw any error?

Comment: @prtdomingo  it doesn't compile

Comment: @Kevin Wallis look for an answer here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7504438/why-does-casting-give-cs0030-while-as-works

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496096/casting-vs-using-the-as-keyword-in-the-clr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `as` is a safe cast, i.e. it will not raise an exception or a compiler error if the type can not be casted. It will simply return `null`. `c1.container` should be `null` after using `as`.

From your code, you may be trying to use variant generics. Check out [this link at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/mt654055.aspx) to help achieve what you were trying to do. You'll [have to use interfaces though](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2541538/4038191), and cannot make a type parameter both covariant and contravariant.

Comment: cl.container  isn't null running his code

Comment: @MaksimSimkin try using a class deriving `MyClass` as the type parameter. `c1.container` will definitely be null.